# delimit grep output from xargs

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

Is there a way to delimit the outputs from running grep with each arg from xargs? 
I'm trying to run this:

`echo 'pattern1\npattern2' | xargs -I{} grep -r  '{}' *`

For context, I'm trying to test existence of each pattern within a directory; something like this:

```
#pattern exit_status
pattern1 0
pattern2 1
```

I don't exactly need the delimiter, but want one as it would allow me to count per pattern.  If there's a better way to do this I'd be open to that, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run something like this:

```
printf '%s\n' pattern1 pattern2 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'grep -rq "$1"; echo "$1 $?"' sh {}
```

This would `echo` each pattern and its exit status of the recursive `grep` command.

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing with `sh`?  and what "$1" is referencing for grep?

Comment: I'm using `sh` with a command string since there is more than one command to execute (`grep` and `echo`) and this cannot be done with `xargs` alone. `$1` is the first parameter passed as argument from `xargs` (one pattern=`{}`).

Comment: One last thing regarding `sh`: are you first defining the command to run, then running it with the trailing `sh {}`?

Why can't we pass in the string replacement from `xargs` directly into the command string?

Comment: There is only one parameter for each `sh` invocation, so you can use the placeholder in the command string: `sh -c 'grep -rq "{}"; echo "{} $?"'`. It's a matter of choice ;)